# Receive a floating point in Matlab from bytes

Tags: matlab, floating-point

I would like to send a floating number over a serial COM to Matlab and interpret it as a single precision floating number.

I can send the data over the serial as byte packets.

So on sender side I shift 32bit floating point number by 8, mask it and send it

```
(byte)((number >> 8) & 0x000000FF)
(byte)((number >> 16) & 0x000000FF)
...
\r\n (line termination)
```

Now, on Matlab I connect to the COM and receive by using `fscanf(s,'%f')` where s is the serial instance. It reads the bytes till the termination line.

Now, the problem is that the output on Matlab is not the same as I sent. I believe the problem is whether in the different float representation or different sending order.

eg. If I send decimal `1.2 (0x3f99999a)`, Matlab prints `1.5315e+010`

What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT:

Matlab fscanf http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html

Comment: That sender code is so broken it isn't funny.  Why are you shifting by four bits?  Where did `number` come from, you can't even use `>>` with floating-point?  What makes you think you can use `fscanf` for binary data?  And what happens when one of the data bytes happens to be `\r` or `\n`?

Comment: @Ben Voigt Sorry. I meant shifting by 8 bits. Typo when created the thread. Matlab terminates the reading by itself when it receives \r or \n. Number is a float in C. I have added the link to the matlab function which states that it is possible to receive and format binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `number` is of type double which is 64-bit. You should perform the shift for 64-bit instead of 32-bit. Otherwise you can declare the number as uint32 type and do the 32-bit shift.

Answer (score 1):

Try `fread` instead of `fscanf`, when the data is binary.